# Pagination position in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can I echo current position in pagination with $dataprovider? Like the one thats shown by using GridView "Showing 26-50 of 246 items"

I show pagination with

```
<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $dataProvider->pagination]) ?>
```

but cant find where current item counts are stored in order to make something like

```
<?= "Showing ".$first_item_in_page."-".$total_items_in_page." of ".$total_items_in_db." items" ?>
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are properties you can use:

- `$dataProvider->count` returns the number of data models in the current page.
- `$dataProvider->totalCount` returns the total number of data models.
- `$dataProvider->pagination->page` returns the zero-based current page number.
- `$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize` returns the number of items per page.

Comment: Thankyou @Bizley ! Ive modified it to show <?= "Showing page: ".($dataProvider->pagination->page*$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize+1)."-".($dataProvider->pagination->page*$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize+$dataProvider->count)." of ".$dataProvider->totalCount." items" ?>

Comment: Just realized that we must do a $dataProvider->prepare(); before showing results for the pagination to work properly. Thanks again